# why the char comparison "if(c>='a' && c<='z')" is not portable?

Tags: c, comparison, char

Some one told me that the char comparison `if(c>='a' && c<='z')` is not portable.

example

```
int main() {
    char c;
    scanf("%c", &c);
    if(c>='a' && c<='z')
        printf("lower case\n");
}
```

Any proof that the char comparison `if(c>='a' && c<='z')` is not portable?

Comment: I think it would always work in practice, but there is no theoretical guarantee that the codes for characters are continuous or increasing.

Comment: use `islower(c)` instead to be portable

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The C standard does not guarantee that only lower case letters appear between `'a'` and `'z'` in the execution character set.

In the EBCDIC encoding, there are other characters between `'a'` and `'z'`, and some C implementations use EBCDIC.

The C standard does guarantee that the digits are consecutive, so `'0' <= d && d <= '9'` does test whether `d` is a decimal digit character.

Answer (score 1):

*Any proof that the char comparison if(c>='a' && c<='z')) is not portable?*

```
c = '~';

if  (c>='a' && c<='z'))
{
   printf("Yes\n");
}
```

will print `Yes` in a AS/400 from IBM because in EBCDIC encoding `~` is between `a` and `z`.